# Strange symbols obtained after the integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, symbols

Suppose the function

```
dsigmaapproxtemp[p_, me_, mS_, y_, c1_, c2_] =(188416 c2^2 p^12+122880 c2^2 y p^12-163840 c2^2 (2 y^2-1) p^12-118784 c2^2 (4 y^3-3 y) p^12-24576 c2^2 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^12-4096 c2^2 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^12+14336 c1^2 p^10+348160 c2^2 me^2 p^10-122880 c2^2 mS^2 p^10+126976 c1 c2 me p^10-14336 c1^2 y p^10+159744 c2^2 me^2 y p^10-90112 c2^2 mS^2 y p^10-28672 c1 c2 me y p^10-8192 c1^2 (2 y^2-1) p^10-311296 c2^2 me^2 (2 y^2-1) p^10+98304 c2^2 mS^2 (2 y^2-1) p^10-147456 c1 c2 me (2 y^2-1) p^10+13312 c1^2 (4 y^3-3 y) p^10-157696 c2^2 me^2 (4 y^3-3 y) p^10+86016 c2^2 mS^2 (4 y^3-3 y) p^10+26624 c1 c2 me (4 y^3-3 y) p^10-6144 c1^2 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^10-36864 c2^2 me^2 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^10+24576 c2^2 mS^2 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^10+20480 c1 c2 me (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^10+1024 c1^2 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^10-2048 c2^2 me^2 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^10+4096 c2^2 mS^2 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^10+2048 c1 c2 me (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^10+29696 c2^2 mS^4 p^8+80384 c1^2 me^2 p^8-14336 c1^2 mS^2 p^8-203776 c2^2 me^2 mS^2 p^8-71680 c1 c2 me mS^2 p^8+25600 c2^2 mS^4 y p^8-93696 c1^2 me^2 y p^8+14336 c1^2 mS^2 y p^8-148480 c2^2 me^2 mS^2 y p^8+4096 c1 c2 me mS^2 y p^8-20480 c2^2 mS^4 (2 y^2-1) p^8-6144 c1^2 me^2 (2 y^2-1) p^8+8192 c1^2 mS^2 (2 y^2-1) p^8+167936 c2^2 me^2 mS^2 (2 y^2-1) p^8+90112 c1 c2 me mS^2 (2 y^2-1) p^8-24064 c2^2 mS^4 (4 y^3-3 y) p^8+27904 c1^2 me^2 (4 y^3-3 y) p^8-13312 c1^2 mS^2 (4 y^3-3 y) p^8+144896 c2^2 me^2 mS^2 (4 y^3-3 y) p^8-2048 c1 c2 me mS^2 (4 y^3-3 y) p^8-9216 c2^2 mS^4 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^8-8704 c1^2 me^2 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^8+6144 c1^2 mS^2 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^8+35840 c2^2 me^2 mS^2 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^8-18432 c1 c2 me mS^2 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^8-1536 c2^2 mS^4 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^8+256 c1^2 me^2 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^8-1024 c1^2 mS^2 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^8+3584 c2^2 me^2 mS^2 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^8-2048 c1 c2 me mS^2 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^8-3584 c2^2 mS^6 p^6+7424 c1^2 mS^4 p^6+29696 c2^2 me^2 mS^4 p^6+18432 c1 c2 me mS^4 p^6-39680 c1^2 me^2 mS^2 p^6-3584 c2^2 mS^6 y p^6-6400 c1^2 mS^4 y p^6+26368 c2^2 me^2 mS^4 y p^6+1536 c1 c2 me mS^4 y p^6+33536 c1^2 me^2 mS^2 y p^6+2048 c2^2 mS^6 (2 y^2-1) p^6-5120 c1^2 mS^4 (2 y^2-1) p^6-20480 c2^2 me^2 mS^4 (2 y^2-1) p^6-24576 c1 c2 me mS^4 (2 y^2-1) p^6+29696 c1^2 me^2 mS^2 (2 y^2-1) p^6+3328 c2^2 mS^6 (4 y^3-3 y) p^6+6016 c1^2 mS^4 (4 y^3-3 y) p^6-25216 c2^2 me^2 mS^4 (4 y^3-3 y) p^6-2304 c1 c2 me mS^4 (4 y^3-3 y) p^6-32896 c1^2 me^2 mS^2 (4 y^3-3 y) p^6+1536 c2^2 mS^6 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^6-2304 c1^2 mS^4 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^6-9216 c2^2 me^2 mS^4 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^6+6144 c1 c2 me mS^4 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^6+9984 c1^2 me^2 mS^2 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^6+256 c2^2 mS^6 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^6+384 c1^2 mS^4 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^6-1152 c2^2 me^2 mS^4 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^6+768 c1 c2 me mS^4 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^6-640 c1^2 me^2 mS^2 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^6+224 c2^2 mS^8 p^4-1920 c1^2 mS^6 p^4-448 c2^2 me^2 mS^6 p^4-1664 c1 c2 me mS^6 p^4+14272 c1^2 me^2 mS^4 p^4+224 c2^2 mS^8 y p^4+1408 c1^2 mS^6 y p^4-448 c2^2 me^2 mS^6 y p^4+256 c1 c2 me mS^6 y p^4-11648 c1^2 me^2 mS^4 y p^4-128 c2^2 mS^8 (2 y^2-1) p^4+1536 c1^2 mS^6 (2 y^2-1) p^4+256 c2^2 me^2 mS^6 (2 y^2-1) p^4+2560 c1 c2 me mS^6 (2 y^2-1) p^4-11008 c1^2 me^2 mS^4 (2 y^2-1) p^4-208 c2^2 mS^8 (4 y^3-3 y) p^4-1344 c1^2 mS^6 (4 y^3-3 y) p^4+416 c2^2 me^2 mS^6 (4 y^3-3 y) p^4-128 c1 c2 me mS^6 (4 y^3-3 y) p^4+11456 c1^2 me^2 mS^4 (4 y^3-3 y) p^4-96 c2^2 mS^8 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^4+384 c1^2 mS^6 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^4+192 c2^2 me^2 mS^6 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^4-896 c1 c2 me mS^6 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^4-3264 c1^2 me^2 mS^4 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^4-16 c2^2 mS^8 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^4-64 c1^2 mS^6 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^4+32 c2^2 me^2 mS^6 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^4-128 c1 c2 me mS^6 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^4+192 c1^2 me^2 mS^4 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^4+184 c1^2 mS^8 p^2+336 c2^2 me^2 mS^8 p^2-112 c1 c2 me mS^8 p^2-2160 c1^2 me^2 mS^6 p^2-120 c1^2 mS^8 y p^2+672 c2^2 me^2 mS^8 y p^2-112 c1 c2 me mS^8 y p^2+1552 c1^2 me^2 mS^6 y p^2-160 c1^2 mS^8 (2 y^2-1) p^2+576 c2^2 me^2 mS^8 (2 y^2-1) p^2+64 c1 c2 me mS^8 (2 y^2-1) p^2+1856 c1^2 me^2 mS^6 (2 y^2-1) p^2+116 c1^2 mS^8 (4 y^3-3 y) p^2+336 c2^2 me^2 mS^8 (4 y^3-3 y) p^2+104 c1 c2 me mS^8 (4 y^3-3 y) p^2-1560 c1^2 me^2 mS^6 (4 y^3-3 y) p^2-24 c1^2 mS^8 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^2+112 c2^2 me^2 mS^8 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^2+48 c1 c2 me mS^8 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^2+304 c1^2 me^2 mS^6 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1) p^2+4 c1^2 mS^8 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^2+16 c2^2 me^2 mS^8 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^2+8 c1 c2 me mS^8 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^2+8 c1^2 me^2 mS^6 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y) p^2+18 c1^2 me^2 mS^8+54 c1^2 me^2 mS^8 y-24 c1^2 me^2 mS^8 (2 y^2-1)-49 c1^2 me^2 mS^8 (4 y^3-3 y)+6 c1^2 me^2 mS^8 (8 y^4-8 y^2+1)-5 c1^2 me^2 mS^8 (16 y^5-20 y^3+5 y))/(128 p^2 (4 p^2-mS^2) ((y-1) (y+1) (-mS^4+36 p^2 mS^2-96 p^4+(-3 mS^4-36 p^2 mS^2+32 p^4) y^2-4 (mS^4-16 p^4) y) me^2+4 (mS^2 p-4 p^3)^2))
```

I need to integrate it over the variable $y$. So I write

```
sigma[p_,me_,mS_,y_,c1_,c2_]=Integrate[dsigmaapproxtemp[p, me, mS, y, c1, c2] ,y]
```

However, the integral includes strange symbol #1, for example, Log[y-#1]. What is this symbol and how to avoid it?

Comment: look for [`RootSum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootSum.html)

Answer (score 2):

Those are [`Slot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)s which appear inside of `RootSum` as a part of `Function`. You can apply `ToRadicals` to get rid of them:

```
ToRadicals @ Integrate[dsigmaapproxtemp[p, me, mS, y, c1, c2] ,y]
```